# Javascript canvas highscore glitch

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a bug squashing game and my highscore function does not work.

```
if (high_score < monstersCaught) {
    highscore = monstersCaught;
}
```

This finds out if the `high_score` is less than `monstersCaught` so if it knows to update the `high_score`. It might help to know that this is nested inside of another *if* statement.
Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/FrPJP/1/

Answer (score 2):

You have highscore instead of high_score.

Comment: Yes thank you so much it totally works now!!!

Comment: You're welcome. We all have a mental block now and then...

Comment: hahahaha yup we do @ignatius_gim